# overriding front template translations doesn't work

Tags: translation, prestashop, overriding

I'm working on prestashop and I'm Trying to override "order detail page" in front (customer's details orders).

This is how I did :

1. I copied file **\controllers\front\OrderDetailController.php** into folder **\override\controllers\front\OrderDetailController.php**
2. I copied also default template file **order-detail.tpl** into folder *override/customtemplate/order-detail.tpl*
3. And In **OrderDetailController.php** I have specified template directory like that 
   **$this->setTemplate(_PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_ . '/themes/parfum_evo/order-detail.tpl');**

I tried, it works fine except translations. Even watching the documentation, no test solution seems to work.

Could anyone help me? Thank you in advance :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php override sits in the correct place. As for the other, you specified the path the override/customtemplate/order-detail.tpl but then placed it in override/themes/parfum_evo/order-detail.tpl. I take it as customtemplate is farfum_evo really, but you need to add another one named themes, after override, using that structure. I think. Because there is a hook named

DisplayOverrideTemplate

Which should take care of this, while I believe setTemplate for controllers will always grab from the main theme folder